# How should these Rails Models be associated?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-associations, rails-models

I have over thought this to the point that I'm only getting confused now.

I have a Rails app with the following as models: User, Site, Tutorial, TutorialStep.

A user can create many tutorials and each tutorial has a site it lives on, and each tutorial has many tutorial steps.

The model I'm having the issue with is Site.

A user has many tutorials and has many tutorials steps through tutorial. A tutorial belongs to a user and has many tutorial steps and lastly a tutorial step belongs to a tutorial.

Now should a site belong to a user and a tutorial, or just a tutorial?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would structure the relations as follows:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :tutorials
  has_many :sites, through: :tutorials
  ...
end

class Site < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :tutorials
  has_many :users, through: :tutorials
  ...
end

class Tutorial < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :tutorial_steps
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :site
  ...
end

class TutorialStep < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :tutorial
  ...
end
```

Making a `Site` belong to a `User` Binds that site to a single user only, which then means that multiple users cannot place tutorials on the same site, you would have to make duplicate entries of the same site to be able to achieve this, which in my opinion is not very good model design, because if in real life multiple users have different tutorials on the same site, you want to be able to reflect that same behaviour in your models and data. Therefore if you want to be able to reference sites from a `User`, and reference users from a `Site`, I would recommend using a has many through relation on the table that links them, ie the tutorial table, like I have show above.

Comment: Thanks! This makes a lot of sense. Other answers are close to this but are missing the `has_many :users, through: :tutorials` on `Site`. As per your point, this is important to have because then I can reference sites from a User.

Answer (score 0):

### User

```
has_many :tutorials
```

### Site

```
has_many :tutorials
```

### Tutorial

```
has_many :tutorial_steps
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :site
```

Tutorial would need site id and user id to correctly map association to user and site

Tutorial Table (... user_id,site_id)

Comment: What do you think of John's answer above using the has_many through relationship for User and Site?

Answer (score 0):

It should look like this,

user.rb

```
has_many :tutorials
has_many :tutorial_steps, through: :tutorials
```

site.rb

```
has_many :tutorials
```

tutorial.rb

```
has_many :tutorial_steps
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :site
```

tutorial_step.rb

```
belongs_to :tutorial
has_one :user, through: :tutorial
has_one :site, through: :tutorial
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks for your input! John's answer is pretty much this but also adds `has_many :users, through: tutorials` on the Site model and vice versa on the User model. His point was that this way you can reference sites from a `User`. What are your thoughts on that?

Answer (score 0):

As far as i understand from your question you can use `has_one` relation.

**has_one : Specifies a one-to-one association with another class**

you can create a has_one relation with site and tutorial

> app/models/user.rb

```
has_many :tutorials,->{ includes :site}
has_many :tutorial_steps, through: :tutorials
```

includes is `eager loading` technique which lets you to fetch site along with the tutorial relation

> app/models/tutorial.rb

```
belongs_to :site
belongs_to :user
has_many :tutorial_steps
```

> app/models/site.rb

```
  has_one :tutorial
```

> app/models/tutorial_step.rb

```
belongs_to :tutorial
```

Comment: Thanks for the input Vishal, however a one-to-one relationship won't work here because even though a tutorial has one site, a site can have many tutorials. I should have made that more clear, thank you.

Comment: in that case you can go with the @john post. happy that you got a solution for it. :)